# recusive pyramide with only 1 argument

Tags: c, recursion, canvas

I just can't figure out how this is possible:

/*
Draw a pyramid: the bottom line is completely black, the second bottom line leaves the first and last pixels white, the third bottom line leaves the first two and last two pixels white, etc.

Solve the problem without using loops.
*/

I have no clue how to do this without using loops or giving the function more arguments.

```c
Canvas pyramid(Canvas c) {

    return c;
}
```

Helpful function:

```c
Canvas vertical_line(Canvas c, int x, int y, int height) {
    if(height > 0 && is_on_canvas(c, x, y)) {
        canvas_set_black(c, x, y);
        vertical_line(c, x, y + 1, height - 1);
    }
    return c;
}
```

commands for the Canvas are:

```c
canvas_height(c) // gives hight in pixels
canvas_width(c) // gives width in pixels
canvas_set_black(c, int x, in y) // sets pixels at (x,y) black 
canvas_set_white(c, int x, int y)
```

canvas starts at x = 0, y = 0

Comment: are you allowed to write helper functions?

Comment: Yes I am,  had to write the function:
```
Canvas vertical_line(Canvas c, int x, int y, int height) {
    if(height > 0 && is_on_canvas(c, x, y)) {
        canvas_set_black(c, x, y);
        vertical_line(c, x, y + 1, height - 1);
    }
    return c;
}
```
Should have posteted this in the question aswell

Comment: then make a `pyramid_internal` with as many arguments as you need and use the `pyramid` entry point to call it with some starting values

Comment: Don't describe the desired output. _Show_ an example.

Comment: what is `Canvas` type

Comment: @0___________ what's inside of `Canvas` doesn't really seem to be relevant. Functions to set pixels and to get dimensions are provided. No need to get hands dirty with the details.

Comment: What's the output supposed to be exactly? Any code edits should be added to the post rather than put into comments.

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start, you should visualize how the final result is supposed to look:

[image: Pixels of the pyramid]

As this seems to be some homework task for recursion, I will only provide incomplete (and due to lack of your environment also untested) code.
In any real world task there would not be a restriction to not use loop.

First, you need to get information about your canvas. What are the limits of your pyramid:

```c
Canvas pyramid(Canvas c) {
  int height = canvas_height(c);
  int width = canvas_width(c);

  draw_lines(c, height, width, 0 /*start with first line*/ );
  return c;
}
```

After retrieving dimensions, this starts drawing a line at `y=0` which I assume is bottom line. If that is top line, you need to adjust accordingly.

Now lets look at each line:

```c
// Draw a line and call itself to draw next line.
void draw_lines(Canvas c, int height, int width, int line)
{
  draw_pixels_in_line(... 0 /* start with first pixel*/, line); // Draw one line.

  if (line < height-1)
  { // More lines to draw, add another recursive call.
    draw_lines( ..., line +1);
  }
}
```

The we do similar thing within each horizontal line:

```c
// Draw two pixels within a line and call itself to draw next pixel.
// Both a pixel on the left and on the right of the line are drawn.
// Therefore column only goes from 0 .. width/2.
// Color is chosen based on our position within the line
void draw_pixels_in_line(Canvas c, int height, int width, int line, int column)
{
  if (column > line)
  {
    canvas_set_white(c, column, line);
    canvas_set_white(c, width - column - 1, line);
  }
  else
  {
    canvas_set_black(c, column, line);
    canvas_set_black(c, width - column - 1, line);
  }

  if (column < width/2 - 1)
  { // More pixels to draw in between, add another recursive call.
    draw_pixels_in_line( ... , column +1);
  }
}
```

Also, place prototypes of these functions above your `pyramid` function:

```c
void draw_lines(Canvas c, int height, int width, int line);
void draw_pixel_in_line(Canvas c, int height, int width, int line, int column);
```

You may need to add some extra handling for cases where the dimensions of the canvas do not fit nicely for the pyramid.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use recursion, like in the 2 examples below.

The loops are changed by functions calls, but the logic is the same.

#### a `plot` function to draw a line of pixels

You may need to draw in a canvas or whatever, but it makes no difference to the code, so this `plot` thing here can abstract the issue of displaying the data. I will use `*` for foreground and `.` for background pixels and `printf` the string

```
void plot(char* patt) { printf("%s\n", patt); }
```

#### the `plot` recursive function

```
void prmd(char* pattern, unsigned st, unsigned en)
{
    plot(pattern);
    if ((en < st)) return;
    pattern[st++] = pattern[en--] = '.';
    prmd(pattern, st, en);
}
```

This function do what you need to have done. Just pass a string, the start and end point. In your case, `0` is the first position to be *cleared* and `strlen(pattern)-1` is the last

#### `main` for a test

```
int main(void)
{
    char pattern1[] = "**********";  // 10
    printf(
        "\n\"%s\" [len %llu]\n\n", pattern1,
        strlen(pattern1));
    prmd(pattern1, 0, (int)(strlen(pattern1) - 1));

    char pattern2[] = "***********";  // 11
    printf(
        "\n\"%s\" [len %llu]\n\n", pattern2,
        strlen(pattern2));
    prmd(pattern2, 0, (int)(strlen(pattern2) - 1));
    return 0;
}
```

#### output

```
"**********" [len 10]

**********
.********.
..******..
...****...
....**....
..........

"***********" [len 11]

***********
.*********.
..*******..
...*****...
....***....
.....*.....
...........
```

### example 2

This function

```
int test_for(int sz)
{
    if (sz <= 0) return -1;
    const int limit = 30;
    printf("   Testing for %u [max %u]\n", sz, limit);
    int       n = (sz > limit ? sz : limit);  // some limit
    char*     p = malloc(1 + sz);
    if (p == NULL) return -1;
    int val     = '*';
    memset(p, val, sz);
    *(p + sz) = 0;
    plot(p, 0, sz-1);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

tests for a given size, to make testing easier

#### `main` for a second test

```
int main(void)
{
    for ( int i = 7; i>0; i-=1) test_for(i);
    return 0;
}
```

produces

```
   Testing for 7 [max 30]
*******
.*****.
..***..
...*...
.......
   Testing for 6 [max 30]
******
.****.
..**..
......
   Testing for 5 [max 30]
*****
.***.
..*..
.....
   Testing for 4 [max 30]
****
.**.
....
   Testing for 3 [max 30]
***
.*.
...
   Testing for 2 [max 30]
**
..
   Testing for 1 [max 30]
*
.
```

### complete code for these test

```
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void p_line(char*);
void plot(char*, int, int);
int test_for(int);

int main(void)
{
    for ( int i = 7; i>0; i-=1) test_for(i);
    return 0;
}

void p_line(char* L) { printf("%s\n", L); }

void plot(char* pattern, int st, int en)
{
    p_line(pattern);
    if (en < st) return;
    pattern[st++] = pattern[en--] = '.';
    plot(pattern, st, en);
}

int test_for(int sz)
{
    if (sz <= 0) return -1;
    const int limit = 30;
    printf("   Testing for %u [max %u]\n", sz, limit);
    int       n = (sz > limit ? sz : limit);  // some limit
    char*     p = malloc(1 + sz);
    if (p == NULL) return -1;
    int val     = '*';
    memset(p, val, sz);
    *(p + sz) = 0;
    plot(p, 0, sz-1);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```